Choosing Between Dependency Injection and Inheritance for Accessing Constants
I have multiple classes that need access to the same set of constants. Currently, I have defined these constants in a separate class like so:
public  class ConfigurationConstants
{
    public const string Const1= "const1";
    public const string Const2= "Const2";
}

I'm considering two approaches for accessing these constants in other classes:

Using inheritance, like in the following code:

public class DeleteQueryHandler : ConfigurationConstants, IRequestHandler<DeleteQuery, ErrorOr<Deleted>>
{
}


public class CreateQueryHandler : ConfigurationConstants, IRequestHandler<CreateQuery, ErrorOr<Deleted>>
{
}


Using dependency injection (DI) by passing the ConfigurationConstants instance through the constructors of the classes, as shown here:

public class DeleteQueryHandler : ConfigurationConstants, IRequestHandler<DeleteQuery, ErrorOr<Deleted>>
{
  public DeleteQueryHandler (ConfigurationConstants)
  {..}
}

I'm unsure which approach is more appropriate in terms of best practices, maintainability, and performance. Additionally, I'm open to any other suggestions for achieving this goal.

Those 3 are completely unrelated concepts. Neither inheritance nor DI are good options. Constants don't change so compilers simply replace any reference to them with the actual value

Why not write ConfigurationConstants.Const1 to access the values of the constants?

A better question would be whether you should use constants, static readonly fields or configuration settings. If there's any chance that the values can change, avoid constants, especially public ones. Otherwise you'll have to recompile every project that uses those constants. If the values can change after deployment or based on some criteria, use configuration settings

If they are truly constant the simplest way is to just use ConfigurationConstants.Const1. There is little to no advantage of using "inheritance" for constants, and I do not even see how dependency injection could work for constants.
Note that you may need to consider the lifetime of the constant value. If the constant value is used by some third party it might mean "can never ever change". If it is only used internally it might mean "constant for this version of the application". If you intend it to mean "constant for the current application instance", and then you should probably use a read only configuration object and use dependency injection to pass the configuration object to users.

I do not even see how dependency injection could work for constants - you get the injector to inject an instance of a class that is stuffed full of public constants?! "Just because you can, doesn't mean..."

@flackoverstow yea, but I assume "constant" implies const or static readonly, and they can only be accessed in a static context, so talking about an "instance" makes no sense to me.

I agree, though nothing precludes putting constants in an instances and as any engineer if reasonable experience will have seen, people do the most bizarre things!
